# regex with python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, preg-match

I want to extract a  file, it should start with `[{"linkId":"changeDriveLink"`  and finish by a text just befor `,"zone"`

my input is:

```
[{"linkIdsd":"changeDridsdve [{"linkId":"changeDriveLink","url":"/drive
/3696434","zoneId":"forceAjax"},{"linkId":"printProductsFormSubst","url":"/drive/rayon.pagetemplate.substitutionlist.printproductsformsubst","zoneId":"forc
,"zone"
```

and i want to have:

```
[{"linkId":"changeDriveLink","url":"/drive
    /3696434","zoneId":"forceAjax"},{"linkId":"printProductsFormSubst","url":"/drive/rayon.pagetemplate.substitutionlist.printproductsformsubst","zoneId":"forc
```

how can i do this by regex please?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sample of your json input.

Comment: thanks, i edited my question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression

```
re.compile(r'^\[\{"linkId":"changeDriveLink".*,"zone"', re.DOTALL)
```

should do this. The `.*` in the middle represents any character, and the `re.DOTALL` makes sure, that even newlines are matched, in case your json is pretty-printed.

But I think it would be better, to load the file with the `json` package, and then check if it satisfies your requirements:

```
import json

with open('filename_here.json', 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

if data[0]['linkId'] == 'changeDriveLink':
    # then its OK
else:
    # not OK
```

Based on the string you've given, your json is a `list` (array), and its first element is a `dict`, and the `dict` has a `'linkId'` key with the value `'changeDriveLink'`. This is what I check in the `if` statement.

**EDIT:**

Now I understand what you want to do. 
First, you should omit the `^` charachter from the beggining of the expression, since the string you provided is not the start of the json file, it should be the beginning of the result.
Then, you can get the string you want with e.g. grouping:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'.*(?P<result>\[\{"linkId":"changeDriveLink".*),"zone"', re.DOTALL)
match_obj = pattern.match('your_json_string')
if match_obj is not None:
    the_string_you_want = match_obj.group('result')
```

What I used here is called named grouping, you can read more about in in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: thanks, i know how extract json, my problem is regex, i tested your regular expression but it deosn't work

Comment: could you provide some sample json files?

Comment: Hi Máté, i add the input and the output that i need, thanks

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) package and search in the structure is better than writing a complex regex, which will be unreadable and quite hard to debug.

You can visit this post ([Parsing json and searching through it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383136/parsing-json-and-searching-through-it)) for more ideas.